# Trying to filter out values in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Can anyone assist me with this? I am trying to filter all records with Cat inside of it. But my method does not work. please see code below

```
    const people = [
      { name: "Kerrie", skills: ["Cat", "Rat", "Orange"] },
      { name: "Mario", skills: ["Mouse", "Dog"] },
      { name: "Jacquline", skills: ["Cat", "Pineapple"] },
      { name: "Kathy", skills: ["Cat", "Java"] },
      { name: "Anna", skills: ["Cat", "Dog"] },
      { name: "Matt", skills: ["Apple", "Dog"] },
      { name: "Matt", skills: ["Apple", "Mango", "Rat"] },
    ];

//code below is what I am trying to use to filter
    people.indexOf("Cat")
    }
```

Comment: `people.filter(p => p.skills.indexOf('Cat') >= 0)`

Comment: or `includes` instead of `indexOf`: `people.filter(p => p.skills.includes('Cat'))`

Comment: you want records with cat, but I can't find such keyword in your attempt at all?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Yeah, I avoided that to not run into "It doesn't work in IE" comments :)

Comment: IE was deprecated ! `http://www.ie6death.com/`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Yes it does. From IE 9.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen ahh. I was looking at `CSS Filter` on caniuse

Comment: Thank you all soo much the assistance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const people = [
      { name: "Kerrie", skills: ["Cat", "Rat", "Orange"] },
      { name: "Mario", skills: ["Mouse", "Dog"] },
      { name: "Jacquline", skills: ["Cat", "Pineapple"] },
      { name: "Kathy", skills: ["Cat", "Java"] },
      { name: "Anna", skills: ["Cat", "Dog"] },
      { name: "Matt", skills: ["Apple", "Dog"] },
      { name: "Matt", skills: ["Apple", "Mango", "Rat"] },
    ];
    
let answer = people.filter(x=>x.skills.some(x=> x === "Cat"));

console.log(answer)
```

So in order to filter, [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is mandatory. And in terms of the criteria, you can use either `some` or `indexOf` or `includes`

Answer (score 0):

Simple.  You want to `.filter` your array for elements where the skills property includes `"Cat"`:

```js
 const people = [
      { name: "Kerrie", skills: ["Cat", "Rat", "Orange"] },
      { name: "Mario", skills: ["Mouse", "Dog"] },
      { name: "Jacquline", skills: ["Cat", "Pineapple"] },
      { name: "Kathy", skills: ["Cat", "Java"] },
      { name: "Anna", skills: ["Cat", "Dog"] },
      { name: "Matt", skills: ["Apple", "Dog"] },
      { name: "Matt", skills: ["Apple", "Mango", "Rat"] },
    ];

let result = people.filter( elem => elem.skills.includes("Cat") );
console.log(result)
```